# (scaled) y value for given x value

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I'm modifying some examples [1][2] to draw a line on the canvas. For the end-point I have calculated a data value but now I want to calculate the y value on the canvas.
In the examples I found

```
this.chart.chart.scale.getPixelForValue()
```

which seems deprecated in chart.js 2.6

```
// Used to get data value locations.  Value can either be an index or a numerical value
getPixelForValue: helpers.noop,
```

The first example uses

```
this.calculatePointY()
```

but that doesn't help me either.

What would I use instead?

[Note]: This question is similar but has no answers: [Get Y value of line from X pixel value in ChartJS 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41708349/100009)

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/39118152

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/37222238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **ChartJS - version 2.6**, you should use the following ...

```
chart.scales['y-axis-0'].getPixelForValue(<value>);
```